# Reopen votes aging time isn't directly mentioned in the help center

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, help-center, vote-to-reopen

Quote from [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Close votes age away harmlessly if the threshold is not reached after several days. If the question has at least 100 views, close votes will age away after 4 days; otherwise close votes will age away after 14 days. Each new close vote resets the timer, so all close votes must be at least 4 or 14 days old respectively before aging occurs.

The close votes aging time is mentioned, but reopen votes aging time isn't *directly* mentioned (not through links) in the help center, it should be added.

Comment: I wonder if reopen votes have a similar threshold, or if it's reversed (aka questions with more views have a longer aging period for reopen votes,) or just set at 14 for all

Comment: Just over 20 posts a day were reopened on Stack Overflow in 2021, on average.  Which isn't a _lot_, but it's not nothing.

Comment: @RyanM is that only via reopen votes or do posts that were marked as duplicate then reopened by a gold badge holder for a post tag also count?

Comment: @apokryfos that number counts both categories.

Comment: @WenfangDu It appears to be on-topic here. Feature requests for things that affect SO are perfectly legitimate to ask here on MSO. While it would also be on-topic on MSE, it doesn't appear that it would be clearly superior to have the question there. In general, we only migrate questions which are off-topic where they currently are. I'm not set against migrating it. It just doesn't appear there's a lot of benefit to doing so at this point.